# How can I duplicate the terminal/prompt in a file like using history + sink

Tags: r

I know the `sink` command can divert the `stdout` to a file, but basically if I do this in the command window:

```
library(data.table)
a = 1;
b = 2;
a
[1] 1
```

Only the last line `[1] 1`will be printed in the file.

**Is there a way my whole command window could be printed to a file like it is done with `sink` ?**

NOTE: I want it to be done each time I write something to avoid losing everything if R crashes, meaning I do not want to have to type `printAllCommandToFile()` for this to be done

Comment: I take it that the .Rhistory file is not quite what you want?

Comment: `history()` displays ONLY the commands, I would like commands + results in my example `history()` would print ligns 1 to 4 but not last line...

Comment: FWIW if you open the .history file and re-execute a block of lines, you will re-create the full terminal output.     **However**, I'm not sure what it is you're afraid of losing.  Unless you execute `save.image` , the objects themselves are not saved (lines of ascii text are all that's in the console "log", not the objects).

Comment: @Carl: I work on several projects and sometimes I cannot recreate results I had, because I forget to subset something or because the data changed (It might indeed happen)... There is a lot of data crunching which is not production-ready, so I do not want `sweave` or any complicated thing like this. I understand you might find it strange but I realized that If I could have a snap of what I entered I the command window (commands + displayed output) It would simplify recollection a lot. Hope It is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `txtStart` from the "TeachingDemos" package? See [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/TeachingDemos/docs/wdtxtStart).

Sometimes, when introducing students to R, I've recommended it to help them remember what they did and what the results were, a situation somewhat like you describe.

In my experience on a Linux machine, even if you close R without calling `txtStop`, the output is saved to whatever text file you had specified at the start of your session.

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I wanted, awesome mate! NB: Not sure why it changes the promtp from `R)` to `txtR)` but I don't really care

Comment: @statquant, I think that's just there to remind you that you're currently logging the output. Keep in mind that comments are stripped out, so you need to use `txtComment` if you want to log those too (which I find a bit inconvenient).

Comment: It is described as "a combinaison of sink and history" :), of course as it is using sink it will log "real-time" so if it crashes or if you close the R session the file will persist...

Comment: Ok for the comments, yes it should be an option, like modifying the prompt (look at the `txtStart`code) should also be an option... but hey... very good already :)

Comment: @statquant, [Greg Snow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/430909/greg-snow) is also around on Stack Overflow, so you can always make some of your suggestions to him :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what environment you are in. On my machine (Mac) I can type cmd-A (for select-all) and cmd-S (for save to file) and get a save-dialog. Pretty sure something similar exists on Windows and *Nix devices as well.

Comment: Fair enough... I work on `WinXP` and use `Rterm` for terminal, there is NO `CTRL-A` behaviour (Rterm is using `cmd.exe` which is lame but has a feature I do not want to lose: the `CRTL-R` *nix feature to look for previous command). Anyway it is not what I want, as I said I would like ANY command and "output" (I mean results displayed in the terminal) to be printed to the file, the way it works with `sink`

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a an interactive bash script that sends and grabs everything for you.